# KDE how to remove "Kickoff Application Launcher" popup

Tags: kde

Every time I hover the cursor over K button, I get a popup: "Kickoff Application Launcher". It irritates me a lot. I managed to remove task manager popups in it's properties. But for Kickoff there is no property to remove it.

KDE version: 4.8.5.

How to remove this popup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove it go to System settings -> Workspace -> Workspace button.

Untick "Show informational tips".